# Are there any identifiable characters from works of SF to be found on the cover of Iron Maiden's "Stranger in a Strange Land"?

Tags: character-identification, inspiration, art, iron-maiden, x-bomber

The cover of Iron Maiden's single "[Stranger in a Strange Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land_(Iron_Maiden_song))", features their mascot, Eddie, in a futuristic bar.

[image: The cover of Iron Maiden's "Stranger in a Strange Land"]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land_(Iron_Maiden_song)#Cover_Details) (although uncharacteristically unsourced),

> Eddie's appearance on the single cover is an homage to the Clint Eastwood character "Man with No Name", although it can also be seen as a mixture of Deckard from *Blade Runner* and the "Man with No Name".

---

The two insectoids at the bar look a lot like some of the baddies in *X-Bomber* / *Starfleet* (at the left):

[image: still from X-Bomber]

**Are these insectoids indeed inspired by the characters from *X-Bomber*?**

**Are any of the other characters in that image inspired by any science fiction franchises?**

Comment: The main guy always made me think of Jonah Hex with a few tech upgrades.